# Combine First and Last name into full name (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Long story short, I need pull a first name and last name into one string of text in VBA. This is a part of an automated report so I need it to loop until the next cell is empty.

I can for some reason split a full name into separate text, but combining the two cells is not working for me.

```
Dim first As Variant, last As Variant, full As string

With Worksheets("RG0054_Term Validation")
    .Columns("D").Insert
    .Range("D10").Value = "Employee Name"
    Set first = .Range("B11")
    Set last = .Range("C11")
    full = 0

        Do Until IsEmpty(first.Value)
        Do Until IsEmpty(last.Value)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, full).Formula = first.Value & " " & last.Value
            full = full + 1
            Set last = last.Offset(0, 1)

        Loop

 Set last = .Range("C11")
 Set title = title.Offset(1, 0)

  Loop

  End With


End Sub
```

turn b11 & c11 = d11 for i to 3000 
I am guessing I could do a loop first = i to 3000 and last = 1 to 2 .. but I am not sure how to organize this... Also an explanation of the script logic would be great so I can learn the code syntax rather than regurgitate it.

Comment: How isn't this working? Also, I would switch `ActiveCell` to actually be the cell you want the data in.  Also, it should be `.Value`, not `.Formula`.  Finally, I think you want `last as Range` and `first as Range`, not `Variant`.  What are you ultimately trying to do, in practice? This *might* be possible with a Formula if you're just trying to add some names to cells...

Comment: the value of first doesn't get incremented in the loop. As a result it will never be empty, will it?

Comment: To start, *is not working for me* is not a problem description. In what way **specifically** is it **not working**? And concatenating two strings (first & " " & last) results in a value, not a formula. Then, you set `first` before the loop starts, but never change it inside the loop, so the outer loop should never end (unless the initial `first.Value` is empty when the loop starts, in which case none of your code would run).

Comment: @BruceWayne Ultimately (sorry I was vague on the descrip earlier) I am running reports from five different data systems and would like for them to run seamlessly through a cross-check. I have all the connections of imports through VBA and SQL configured, but now formatting the values (like names, ID numbers, etc.) to run Boolean tests is becoming a hassle. I believe I am more fried from the first half so I am running into problems now.

Comment: @BruceWayne In this problem, all I am trying to do is concatenate without typing functions in, so when I hit my with 'X' amount of sub processes, it runs without me touching this as I have other core business functions to do then to waste my time validating. In this problem the logic stands below:
B11= Bob and C11 = Wilson, in column D11 is where I would like to input this concatenate (join) of cell values.
What you stated successfully pulls the first name, but does not pull the last name.  To answer Ken White... "is not working" means I am not getting errors, and it is not working. thnx <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop. The simplest way would be to find the last row in Col B and then enter the formula in Col D in one go. For example

```
With Worksheets("RG0054_Term Validation")
    Lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Columns(4).Insert
    .Range("D10").Value = "Employee Name"

    .Range("D11:D" & Lrow).Formula = "=B11 & "" "" & C11"
End With
```